# why seekbar is too slow in android

Tags: android, seekbar

I put a seekbar in my activity and a textview
the seekbar will change the font size of text view but if the string is too big the seekbar will be so slow, this is the code please if can anyone check it to see if I've missed something or this slowness is normal

```
public class TextActivity extends Activity {

    public static TextView textview;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private SeekBar seekbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        Window window = getWindow();
        // Unlock the device if locked
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        // Turn screen on if off
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        // Keep screen on
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        // Transition between activities
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.incoming, R.anim.outgoing);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text);
        // Determine The SeekBar and The EditText
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_text_txt);
        // Get Extra From Another Activity
                Intent n = getIntent();
                String mrng = n.getStringExtra("key");
                 textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(mrng));
        // Save Preferences
        prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        float fs = prefs.getFloat("fontsize", 40);
        seekbar.setProgress((int) fs);
        textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, seekbar.getProgress());

        // Programming SeekBar
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
                ed.putFloat("fontsize", textview.getTextSize());
                ed.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, progress);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

any help??

Comment: no one here to help me ???

Comment: I bet the issue is in onStopTrackingTouch(). Have You tried to remove everything from it and check if it gets faster?

Comment: I removed everything from onStopTrackingTouch() and I put on onBackPressed() but the problem still.
any other idea ????

Comment: I've tried Your code (however, lot of info is lack in your question, like what is the text etc) and haven't observed any slowness at all. Do You use some complex html as text (e.g. 3-4 pages of text etc.)? What html do you use? Have You observed the same issue with normal string?

Comment: the text is a big paragraph (about 3000 words) btw with other sring it works fine so the problem is the big paragraph is there any solution

Comment: Actually, it's not possible to change appearance of 3000 the same speed as changing of 1-3 words. I'm not sure about exact purpose of your code, but You may introduce delay before changing text size (e.g. send message to handler with some delay) and change it only in case not new change came before timeout. It will make moving of seekbar smoother, but text appearance will be changed with a delay.